# Data Caching in .NET

Tags: .net, caching

I've been looking at the spring.net approach to caching (using aop), since my project already has a dependency upon spring.

However, I was surprised to find that you can only configure the caching rules declaratively as attributes. You dont seem to be able to configure the caching in a seperation configuration file..

Is anybody aware of a caching framework for .net that allows thr caching rules to be declared within a configuration file?

Comment: Attributes **are** definitely declarative. What exactly you want?

Answer (score 0):

I've started looking at creating a postprocessor and Namespace parser to handle the configuration of the cache...

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc467894.aspx) has a great [Caching Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309502.aspx) and, yes, you can declare the caching framework declaratively through configuration.